# Не могу установить слайдер (PgwSlider) на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Помогите пожалуйста установить слайдер на сайт.

Вот этот слайдер: http://pgwjs.com/pgwslider/

Там есть ссылка на гидхаб, я скачал но там нет файлов HTML. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вообще читали что написано ниже [GitHub](https://github.com/Pagawa/PgwSlider#pgwslider) Readme и тут [http://pgwjs.com](http://pgwjs.com/pgwslider/)?
И наверное надо поискать как нужно работать с Node / NPM о чем в Readme на гит хабе написано.